# Java - List<Integer> sort, comparator and overflow

Tags: java, overflow, comparator

I've the following code that sorts a list in a descending order

```
List<Integer> list=Arrays.asList(Integer.MAX_VALUE, -1);
list.sort((x, y) -> y-x);
System.out.println(list)
```

The result is

```
[-1, 2147483647]
```

**Now, I know that I should not write y-x because it can cause overflow problem.**

But the question is why is the output that? I believed the output would be `[2147483647, -1]` because `-1 - Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `-2147483648`, still a negative integer, ad the operation seems not be affected by overflow problem.
What I did wrong?

Comment: Replace your sort with `list.sort((x, y) -> {System.out.println(y-x + " " + x + " " + y); return y-x;});` and see whether you still think it is not an overflow problem

Comment: I see this output: -2147483648 -1 2147483647, it seems that x and y are swapped

Answer (score 5):

As you can read in [Oracle's Object Ordening Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) near the bottom of the page:

> You might be tempted to replace the final return statement in the
>   Comparator with the simpler:
>
> ```
> return e1.number() - e2.number();
> ```
>
> Don't do it unless you're absolutely
>   sure no one will ever have a negative employee number! **This trick does
>   not work in general because the signed integer type is not big enough
>   to represent the difference of two arbitrary signed integers. If i is
>   a large positive integer and j is a large negative integer, i - j will
>   overflow and will return a negative integer.** The resulting comparator
>   violates one of the four technical restrictions we keep talking about
>   (transitivity) and produces horrible, subtle bugs. This is not a
>   purely theoretical concern; people get burned by it.

The situation described here is what the OP encounters: the difference between the two integers is more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and will therefore overflow during comparison, resulting in an unexpected sorting.

Comment: This is where the journey ends.

Comment: @RobinTopper I always find it weird that people expect overflows to be exceptions...

Comment: Good answer, +1. Unfortunately the tutorial hasn't been updated to use the new `Integer.compare()` method which was added in Java 7.

Answer (score 2):

I just did what exactly @Robin Topper told.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(Integer.MAX_VALUE, -1);
        list.sort((x, y) -> {
            System.out.println("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
            System.out.println("y - x = " + (y - x));
            return y - x;
        });
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

And I got

```
x: -1 y: 2147483647
y - x = -2147483648
[-1, 2147483647]
```

<strike>And we can see that</strike>

[List#sort(Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) applies values onto given `Comparator` in inverse order.

1. With a given `Comparator`,
2. When it's applies with `-1` and `2147483647`,
3. The `(y - x)` part (`2147483647 - -1`) overflowed as `-2147483648` which is negative,
4. And it is true that `-1` is less than `2147483647`.

Here's the sourcecodes.

[List#sort(Comparator)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/List.java#475)

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
default void More ...sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    Object[] a = this.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator) c);
    ListIterator<E> i = this.listIterator();
    for (Object e : a) {
        i.next();
         i.set((E) e);
    }
}
```

[Arrays#sort(Comparator)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#143)

```
public static void sort(int[] a) {
    DualPivotQuicksort.sort(a, 0, a.length - 1, null, 0, 0);
}
```

[DualPovotQuicksort#sort()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java#107)

Comment: "*`List#sort(Comparator)` applies values onto given Comparator **in inverse order***" is not very clear (or is simply wrong). Documentation you included explicitly states that it "Sorts this list **according to the order induced by the specified Comparator**." so sorting applied proper order, but it was Comparator which described descending order (if we add other numbers to list like `Arrays.asList(Integer.MAX_VALUE, -1, 2, 5);` we will see as result `[5, 2, -1, 2147483647]`.

Comment: I want take this answer back, but I can't cuz it's accepted.

Comment: I gave the "inverse order" the following meaning: the sorting algorithm during the list iteration, goes from the end to the start

Answer (score 2):

Before we start you need to know that Comparator considers pair (x,y) as ordered according to its design if `compare(x,y) < 0`
(just like for natural (ascending) order: if `x<y` then `x-y<0`).

---

**Integer overflow**

In mathematical world, if x and y in pair (x,y) are in ascending order we can write it as `x<y` which can also be rewritten as `x-y<0`. Descending order can be represented as `x>y` which can be rewritten as `x-y>0`.
But such rewriting is possible only in mathematical world. In IT world numeric types like `int` have their min and max values, and if we will try to calculate values out of that range we will face [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). Your example is one of that cases. If `x = -1` and  `y = 2147483647` then comparator calculating `y-x` will return `-2147483648`

```
     y       -   x
(2147483647) - (-1) = -2147483648
```

instead of positive `2147483648`.

Because of that, ***incorrect*** (and negative) result is returned, making sorting algorithm "think" that values of `x` and `y` are in *correct* order.

**Wait, if that result was mistake, then how we got as result elements in *ascending* order `[-1, 2147483647]`? Shouldn't that "incorrect" order be descending?**

No, because Comparator returning `y-x` describes **descending** order. Take a look. Elements `x` and `y` used in any `Comparator.compare(x,y)` are considered to be in correct order when `Comparator.compare(x,y)<0`. If we use code of our comparator we will get `y-x<0`, in order words `y<x` (or simpler `x>y`).

It can also be easily observed if we change a little elements in list

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(-1, 2, 5);
```

where after sorting we will get

```
[5, 2, -1]
```

---

In short:

- sorting algorithm uses Comparator which describes *descending* order
- but since Comparator makes mistake (caused by integer overflow) it doesn't inform sorting algorithm about need to "change order" of `-1` and `2147483647` so they stay at their positions.